# Does agile approach support taking a task from a team?

Tags: agile, methodology

Can customer take one of tasks during the planning meeting, which was already assigned to this team, and put it to another team? For example because a customer think that the other team will be faster in implementing it? 
Is it normal for some agile methodologies? If yes, could you, please, provide me with the source of this information(book or web link), because I do not know how to handle it, especially because of team spirit: such a thing can make people in team demotivated and also there can origin some tenses in between these two teams...

It is part of some agile methodology and what are the constraints to make this thing?

Comment: Agile or not, either the problem is this very productive team has too many other tasks "at this time" or they are in-fact slower than the other team. If this demotivates you, you're fired. Put on the grown-up pants and get more things done. This isn't youth soccer where everyone gets a trophy.

Comment: While there is an Agile Manifesto and many books and processes written for it, Agile is defined by its lack of strict rules. They are more like guidelines. My one sentence description of Agile is "do what works, do not do what does not work." In my opinion, a customer micromanaging workload would _not_ work and should not be done. It only serves to lower morale, disrupt workflow, and generally make developers lose faith in the project. That does not support the end goal of delivering quality software as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 7):

1. Why do you let customers dictate how work gets done? How would they even know about the speed of your teams?
2. To answer your question: no. The team self organises and chooses how to distribute the work. If the customer has some hard deadline in mind, he/she should communicate that deadline and trust the team or teams to meet that deadline. How the teams achieve that is not the concern of the customer.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really an agile 'rulebook' with do's and dont's. People are encouraged to follow common sense based upon some general guidelines.

To answer your question: in my point of view it depends on what you mean by "task".

If you mean implementing a certain functionality, it is up to the Product Owner to decide if functionality needs to be developed or not, and in which timeframe. If he sees that another team will deliver faster he has the option to give it to another team. I am not claiming that it is a good idea to do so in case of existing problems between teams and it will clearly not motivate the first team.

If you mean a pure technical task part of a userstory, it is up to the team to decide how to implement it.